# Trying to get WordPress PHP inside of HTML echo statement

Tags: php, html, wordpress, echo

I thought I had this right after reading many SO articles, but I keep getting errors. Basically, in my content.php page template, I wanted to display a different article tag based on whether you were on the archive or single post page. So I've been doing something like this:

```
<?php if ( is_archive() ) {
    echo '<article id="post-' . the_ID() . '">';
        } else {
    echo '<article id="post-' . the_ID() . ' . "post_class() . '">';
}
?>
```

But what happens here instead of it spits out the ID on the page so the resulting HTML looks like this:

```
1234<article id="post-">Content Goes Here</article>
```

when it should be....

```
<article id="post-1234">Content Goes Here</article>
```

so why isn't this showing up right?

Comment: I got it closer using code like this:
echo '<article id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '"' . post_class() . '>';

So the class code appears but once again, outside of the archive tag. So it's a mess.

Answer (score 2):

`the_ID()` (and quite a few other WP functions) has a variant `get_the_ID()` you'll want to use here. `the_ID()` does its own echo internally; `get_the_ID()` *returns* it.

Answer (score 0):

Just modfy your code to : `the_ID()` by default has echo param true so it print the id, but `get_the_ID()` return the ID which concatenate with your html code. You can get more details by clicking [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID). And also removed the Double Qutoes from else part after the `post_class()` function.

```
<?php if ( is_archive() ) {
    echo '<article id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '">';
        } else {
    echo '<article id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '". post_class() .'>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I see that but after adding that code, I received another error for code that was previously good.

The error is:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /www/webroot/mysite/wordpress/wp-content/themes/orchestra/template-parts/content.php on line 19
That code is:
      <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>

Comment: Also, If I swap those two echo statements, then that error appears on line 14, which is currently the first echo statement that doesn't have the post_class() at the end.

Comment: Yea, getting rid of . post_class() .' worked, but why?

Comment: <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?> error for this line is dur to syntactical, and nothing to do with previous one.

Comment: post_class() was added in worng way. You should be very carfeull when you are using single quote and double quote in echo statement. Closing and Opening should be in a proper manner.